# Autofac InstancePerRequest scope in Azure Function

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, azure-functions

I am trying to have a dependency registered to share an instance per run of Eventhub triggered Azure Function (create new instance each time Azure function runs).

I tried register like below:

```
builder.RegisterType<TrialClass>().As<ITrialClass>().InstancePerRequest();
```

But it fails saying

> No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the
>   scope in which the instance was requested

Is there a way to handle this case ?

.

Comment: I don't think DI is properly supported for Azure Functions yet

Comment: How do you resolve the dependency ?

Comment: I manually resolve the entry point class (which is a .dll and does bulk of the work) from run.csx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. DI not truly supported in Azure Functions today, making registration and injection difficult.
2. Event Hubs triggered functions do not execute within the context of a web request, so to built in *per request* lifetime supported by Autofac would not work

If you have Autofac in a semi working state today, you can try @mjwills' suggestion and define a lifetime scope for a given invocation (this will not be as trivial as using the per request functionality, but doable).

We do have work happening in the WebJobs SDK and the Functions Host/Runtime to enhance the DI story. Some of the work is related or dependent on the .NET core migration you can track [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1576).

Comment: Another related issue in our repo here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/586

Comment: Looks like his comment was removed, but you can find more information about Autofac's lifetime scopes here: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html